# When I want to visit my already installed magento shop the Installation wizard shows up

Tags: database, installation

I recently tried to move my magento shop from the root to a sub directory. 
( I changed the base urls, moved all files and adjusted the .htaccess file).As this didn´t work out I wanted to log in to my mysql data base but seemed to have not the correct password. So I changed the password of the database and also adjusted the local.xml file.
 I also moved the magento files again so that they are in the root directory and again adjusted the .htaccess file, so everything should be as it was, but instead of my shop the Magento Installation Wizard appears.

What does that mean? What am I doing wrong? Please can anybody help me?

Comment: Check app/etc folder, it should config.php and env.php file.

Comment: @SHPatel in Magento 2, yes. But the question mentions local.xml instead, so this is Magento 1

Answer (score 1):

`app/etc/local.xml` must be present and **readable**, otherwise the installation wizard comes up. Check if it is there and file permissions are set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The local.xml is readable as far as I can see. The file permission was 640 and I changed it to 644 now, but still the installation wizard shows up.